# StreamWriter uses synchronous invocation when calling asynchronous methods

Tags: async-await, streamwriter, .net

I am creating a stream like class, that inherits from `Stream`. When I use a `StreamWriter` class to write the information asynchronously:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(messageWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
    await sw.WriteAsync(msg);
```

I can see how `StreamWriter` goes straight to `void Stream.Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` rather than `Task Stream.WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Somebody is very confused about what is going on.  As long as you keep talking about StreamReader writing text, that somebody is you.

Comment: Hmm, it is a bit more than a typo.  It is also present in your question title and the [tag] you used.  And above all, in what you *didn't* say: how do you **know** this?  What are you looking at?  If it is some kind of disassembler then throw it away, it is not giving you good information.

Comment: I fixed that also, thanks. Well it is pretty much what the posts says, I can see in my stream derived class that `Write` is being called rather than `WriteAsync`, and that is what I knew at that time. Now in my answer below I have explained why is happening.

Comment: This is a use case for `IAsyncDisposable` as proposed in [async streams](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/async-streams.md), a candidate feature for C# 8.0, combined with a `using` statement enhancement that that proposal didn't cover.  C# 7.x and below don't have a "nice" way to do asynchronous dispose, so the implicit `Dispose()` call from your `using` statement does the flush synchronously.  The workaround is directly calling and awaiting on `FlushAsync()` so that the synchronous `Dispose()` doesn't have to synchronously flush.

Comment: On .Net Core, you must call DisposeAsync() instead of Dispose() to avoid the synchronous flush.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I spotted the source of confusion.

`StreamWriter` flushes synchronously by default unless you specifically flush asynchronously.

`Stream.Flush` is called when closing, and of course, flushing.

This will invoke `Write` rather than `WriteAsync` in the `messageWriter` stream:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(messageWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi");
```

The `StreamWriter` will buffer the "Hi" message, and it will be released to the underlying stream on the `Flush` invocation synchronously when closing the `StreamWriter`.

So the asynchronous call to `StreamWriter.WriteAsync` could have no effect on the underlying stream (because the buffering), and when calling `StreamWriter.Close`, `StreamWriter.Flush` is called synchronously, and therefore the `Flush` method on the underlying stream.

This code also calls `Write` synchronously:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(messageWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true; // will call Write here to send the UTF8 BOM
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi"); // Write the actual data 
}
```

obviously also this this:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(messageWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi"); 
    sw.Flush(); 
}
```

This will call `WriteAsync`:

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(messageWriter, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi");
    await sw.FlushAsync()
}
```

I have created a simple class to track how the methods are called:

```
public class MSWrite : MemoryStream
{
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write");
    }

    public override Task WriteAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WriteAsync");
        return Task.Run(() => { });
    }
}
```

And this test:

```
Console.WriteLine("Simple");
using(var ms = new MSWrite())
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi");
}
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("AutoFlush");
using (var ms = new MSWrite())
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    sw.AutoFlush = true;
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi");
}
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Flush async");
using (var ms = new MSWrite())
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    await sw.WriteAsync("Hi");
    await sw.FlushAsync();
}
```

Yields:

```
Simple
Write
Write

AutoFlush
Write
WriteAsync

Flush async
WriteAsync
WriteAsync
```

The first write is the UTF8 BOM, the second is the actual data.

Answer (score 3):

No, `StreamWriter.WriteAsync` does in fact call `Stream.WriteAsync` (assuming you are on .NET 4.5). If you are seeing otherwise, please post a stack trace.

Note that the `Stream` base class by default will implement `WriteAsync` as a `Write` done on a thread pool thread. You'll need to override `WriteAsync` in your custom stream to change this behavior.

Comment: It seems that `StreamWriter.WriteAsync` could not call anything at all and just buffer the data. As the flushing was happening synchronously, that is why I didn't see a call to `WriteAsync` but I did to `Write` in the underlying stream.